# Postgresql not starting on Ubuntu 16.04, stuck at performing replication slot checkpoint

Tags: 16.04, systemd, postgresql

We have been working for a while with a PostgreSQL 9.5 instance on a Ubuntu 16.04 DigitalOcean servlet. The database crashed early today and we are no longer able to restart the cluster.

Trying to connect with PSQL will yield **Fatal: Database is starting up error message**.

Listing `systemctl | grep postgresql` lists three objects.

```
postgresql.service (loaded active running)
postgresql@9.5-main.service (loaded failed failed)
system-postgresql.slice (loaded active active)
```

`ps aux | grep postgres` shows me the uninterruptible postgres recovery process. Since I cannot kill this process I decided to disable the startup (update-rc.d postgresql disable) and reboot the machine (hard).

The server boots up without Postgresql processes starting and we manually start the postgresql binary in --single mode with debugging enabled.

> 2017-07-31 23:40:58 UTC [3170-1] DEBUG:  mmap with MAP_HUGETLB failed,
>   huge pages disabled: Cannot allocate memory
>
> 2017-07-31 23:40:58 UTC [3170-2] LOG:  database system was interrupted
>   while in recovery at 2017-07-31 23:27:31 UTC
>
> 2017-07-31 23:40:58 UTC [3170-3] HINT:  This probably means that some
>   data is corrupted and you will have to use the last backup for
>   recovery.
>
> 2017-07-31 23:40:59 UTC [3170-4] DEBUG:  checkpoint record is at
>   1A2/E1605038
>
> 2017-07-31 23:40:59 UTC [3170-5] DEBUG:  redo record is at
>   1A2/E1605038; shutdown FALSE
>
> 2017-07-31 23:40:59 UTC [3170-6] DEBUG:  next transaction ID: 0/54203;
>   next OID: 5501456
>
> 2017-07-31 23:40:59 UTC [3170-7] DEBUG:  next MultiXactId: 1; next
>   MultiXactOffset: 0
>
> 2017-07-31 23:40:59 UTC [3170-8] DEBUG:  oldest unfrozen transaction
>   ID: 654, in database 1
>
> 2017-07-31 23:40:59 UTC [3170-9] DEBUG:  oldest MultiXactId: 1, in
>   database 57814 2017-07-31 23:40:59 UTC [3170-10] DEBUG:  commit
>   timestamp Xid oldest/newest: 0/0
>
> 2017-07-31 23:40:59 UTC [3170-11] DEBUG:  transaction ID wrap limit is
>   2147484301, limited by database with OID 1
>
> 2017-07-31 23:40:59 UTC [3170-12] DEBUG:  MultiXactId wrap limit is
>   2147483648, limited by database with OID 57814
>
> 2017-07-31 23:40:59 UTC [3170-13] DEBUG:  starting up replication
>   slots
>
> 2017-07-31 23:40:59 UTC [3170-14] LOG:  database system was not
>   properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
>
> 2017-07-31 23:40:59 UTC [3170-15] FATAL:  could not open directory
>   "/var/run/postgresql/9.5-main.pg_stat_tmp": No such file or directory

I create the missing pg_stat_tmp directory and restart the process. The hangs now for several hours at **DEBUG: performing replication slot checkpoint**. I have no idea whether this is still doing anything and could not find any great detail about this action.

Comment: Run this `sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i post`, please copy ans paste the output

Comment: Don't post images please copy and paste